# How to get category image by category id in nopcommerce

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nopcommerce

how can I get category image by category id in nopcommerce?

I am working in CategoryNavigationModel page with @model CategoryNavigationModel Model.

Answer (score 2):

**For getting all properties of category model using this method:**

```
var category = await _categoryService.GetCategoryByIdAsync(id);
```

**For getting a picture URL with target Size:**

```
var PictureUrl = await _pictureService.GetPictureUrlAsync(category.PictureId, targetSize: 200);
```

**For getting a full-size picture URL:**

```
var FullPictureUrl = await _pictureService.GetPictureUrlAsync(category.PictureId);
```

**For getting All properties of a picture as Picture Model:**

```
var picture = await _pictureService.GetPictureByIdAsync(category.PictureId);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass category picture id. You can get category image by :

```
var picture = await _pictureService.GetPictureByIdAsync(category.PictureId);
```